# The endLottery function doesn't work on rinkeby from freecodecamp's video

Tags: web3.py, chainlink, vrf

so i was following that ['beginners to expert'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ) video and my lottery contract works fine on kovan but on rinkeby the "start" and "enter" functions work but the "endLottery" shows this, is this because the chainlink vrf won't work or what? the contract has 1.55 link so i think fee shouldn't be an issue.
you can find the contract [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x37223997692d9ca5725360bfb6ced7e7848eb3d5#writeContract) 
you can find the kovan contract [here](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xc3004b2ec871fcabd8ca0a0335af9fa070dea22c#writeContract) (this works as expected)

the code for endLottery:

```
function endLottery() public onlyOwner
{
    lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER;
    bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyhash, fee);
    emit RequestedRandomness(requestId);
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the `endLottery` function call on your Rinkeby contract. Not even a reverted one.  Are you sure you're calling that function in your code at all?

Comment: From what I can see on Etherscan, you provided 0x6168499c0cffcacd319c818142124b7a15e857ab as VRFCoordinator. Can you confirm that this is true? If so, this is an address for VRF V2 coordinator on Rinkeby, while you are using VRF v1 in your code. Either switch to VRF V2 (check the official docs) or provide legacy params to your contract listed here https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/v1/#rinkeby

Comment: Please make this question on the github repo associated with the course.

Comment: @Andrej yup, that was the issue, thanks a lot it works fine now!

Comment: @0xVinx You are welcome